# Using DelegatingHandler to implement HTTP request retry logic

Tags: c#, httpclient, delegatinghandler

I'm trying to implement retry using DelegatingHandler but I also want to set HttpCompletionOption.

My code looks like following :

```
public class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly int MaxRetries;

    public RetryHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, int retryCount = 3)
        : base(innerHandler)
    {
        MaxRetries = retryCount;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < MaxRetries; i++)
        {
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(new RetryHandler(new HttpClientHandler())))
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://ptsv2.com/t/smz9v-1564979884/post");
            var myResult = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            Console.WriteLine(myResult.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

As you can see there is no option to set HttpCompletionOption by inheriting DelegatingHandler, I tried creating CustomDelegatinghandler but in that case I'm unable to use **new RetryHandler(new HttpClientHandler())** as I have used in the main method.

Is there any way to implement DelegatingHandler(or custom) that has/ supports following signature?

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption option,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to include [`HttpCompletionOption`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcompletionoption?view=netframework-4.8) in the message handler signature, because handling `HttpCompletionOption` is responsibility of [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), not of `HttpMessageHandler`.

An `HttpMessageHandler` must initiate a task of sending a request and return a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` as early as possible. In general, it should not perform any buffering of the response content (well, unless it's a middleware created for the purpose of buffering), and that's why it doesn't receive `HttpCompletionOption`. It should always act as if it was passed `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`.

The intended way to specify `HttpCompletionOption` is include it in a call to an overload of `HttpClient` method such as [`GetAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getasync?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_GetAsync_System_String_System_Net_Http_HttpCompletionOption_) or [`SendAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netcore-2.2#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_SendAsync_System_Net_Http_HttpRequestMessage_System_Net_Http_HttpCompletionOption_):

```cs
client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
```

Roughly speaking, `HttpClient` handles `HttpCompletionOption` as follows:

1. Invoke message handler and get a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` ([see code](https://github.com/chenkennt/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs/#L355))
2. If `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead` is specified, then done: return the task to the caller ([see code](https://github.com/chenkennt/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs/#L383))
3. If `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead` is specified, then instead, return the task of `HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsync`, as a continuation of the original `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` ([see code](https://github.com/chenkennt/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs/#L464))

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry I could not understand everything you are trying to say, are you saying that HttpClient will somehow manage HttpCompletionOption and I don't have to change RetryHandler?

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that HttpClient prepared the Message, HttpMessageHandler sends the message and returns Task<HttpResponseMessage> and then HttpClient fetched resutl from response based on HttpCompletionOption??